# In a Multilevel List, for all Levels, how can each row start with the same indent?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

For each level below, how can the green row to be indented the same length as the purple?

The red field fails to resolve the problem above, because inputting one value  fails to adjust for the different lengths of space that integers occupy. For example, the integer `99` occupies more space than `11`; so `99` needs a different 'Text indent' value than `11`, but this difference is not automatically adjusted by the red.

[image]

Comment: The answer is on the right of your dialog. "Add tab stop" at an appropriate setting so that the text after `11` and `99` lines up correctly.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks! Interested in posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, there is a simple way to do this:

Press tab to indent the first line.
Then press tab on the 2nd line and all of the lines will indent to the same indenting point as the 1st/2nd line.

Of course, this is assuming you are going off of the default tab intervals. You can change the indentation point for all of them easily by tabbing the first two lines. Everything is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks. You wrote `Press tab to indent the first line.`; but I do not really intend to indent the first line. The indent only follows the integer with 1 Space that I selected in the 'Adjust List Indents' feature. Does this change your answer?

Comment: @LePressentiment What exactly do you mean? Can you clarify your 2nd and 3rd sentences? Are you intending to indent lines other than the first line?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Any number should be followed by 1 Space and then the first line: I selected this formatting in the  'Adjust List Indents' feature. Then the second (purple) line should automatically start where the first (green) line did. Throughout the above, I never indented anything manually; the  'Adjust List Indents' feature  indented each level (12, 12.1, 12.1.1, ...) automatically per the value in the red box.

Comment: You want a space after each number? There already is by default

Comment: I meant to communicate that only 2 indents existed: the default indent where each number follows 1 space, and the indents chosen in the red box above. Better?

Comment: So you want 11 and 99 to take up the same space and not have an indent when you reach 100?

Comment: Not exactly; I wish the Indent after 11, ..., 99, 100 to start at the same position, so that all text after 11, ..., 99, 100 start at the same place. But maybe [this comment](http://superuser.com/questions/1058902/in-a-multilevel-list-for-all-levels-how-can-each-row-start-with-the-same-inden?noredirect=1#comment1487410_1058902) is the answer?

Comment: Perhaps. Now I know what you mean but I can't help you beyond this. I have this same question myself. The only idea I have is perhaps dragging the number column up to 99 to the right until they align